# How to override the headers of Laminas XML-RPC server response?

Tags: zend-framework, xml-rpc, laminas

Trying to override the headers of [Laminas XML-RPC server](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-xmlrpc/server/#custom-responses) response. The header `Content-Type` should be `application/xml` instead of the default `text/html`. Having read the docs it isn't clear what to do, it states:

> Similar to request objects, `Laminas\XmlRpc\Server` can return custom response objects; by default, a `Laminas\XmlRpc\Response\Http` object is returned, which sends an appropriate `Content-Type` HTTP header for use with XML-RPC. Possible uses of a custom object would be to log responses, or to send responses back to `STDOUT`.
>
> To use a custom response class, use `Laminas\XmlRpc\Server::setResponseClass()` prior to calling `handle()`.

There is a example usage of `setResponseClass()` but not what the class should look like. The only thing that is clear from looking at the source is that it should extend `Laminas\XmlRpc\Response` and that's it.

What I have tried but isn't working:

```
use Laminas\XmlRpc\Response as XmlRpcResponse;

/**
 * HTTP response
 */
class XmlRpcService extends XmlRpcResponse
{
    protected $type = 'application/xml'; // This was just for testing but isn't working either

    /**
     * Override __toString() to send HTTP Content-Type header
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        if (! headers_sent()) {
            header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=' . strtolower($this->getEncoding()));
        }

        return parent::__toString();
    }
}


$server = new \Laminas\XmlRpc\Server();
$server->setClass( 'SomeClass', 'namespace' );
$server->setResponseClass( XmlRpcService::class);
return $server->handle();
```

Hope some one can point me in the right direction of how to override the headers. Related report: https://discourse.laminas.dev/t/how-to-override-the-headers-of-xml-rpc-server-response/1632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm using Laravel I'm able to do the following. This way it isn't required to use a additional class for `$server->setResponseClass( XmlRpcService::class);`. Apparently Laravel can take the `$server->handle()`, which on it's own is already a response, and set the required headers.

```
return response($server->handle(), 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```